# IBM Integration Bus : Monitoring event timestamp change

Tags: monitoring, ibm-integration-bus

We are using IIB v10.0.0.9 and have also enabled event monitoring at different nodes which is getting logged in DB2 database.

The logs gets recorded in database with timestamp in UTC timezone by default. System timestamp is already changed to required timezone but that doesn't help with logging timestamp change.

Is there any configuration at Integration Node level or elsewhere to change/edit/update event timestamp for the logs that are being recorded?

Comment: Can you please clarify the use case you are trying to solve? Monitoring for data change? message flow? something else?

Comment: Monitoring events logging for message flow basically.